# What is the bare minimum requirement for a monad to participate in the composition offered by LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I recall that the C# compiler, when translating from the query expression syntax to calls to the relevant operator methods on the monad, doesn't really care about and doesn't require the monad to have implemented some interfaces.

It doesn't even care of the operator methods are extensions or real instance methods.

But I can't recall the details at all. It seems like there is a bare minimum requirement for the *sequence* itself, which, in my query below would be the `new Foo<string>()` expression.

I recall it doesn't necessarily have to adhere to an interface but it either did have to have a method named `GetEnumerator` or it did have to implement the `IEnumerator<T>` methods. But I could be wrong since my example query shown below works with or without the presence of a `GetEnumerator` method in the `Foo<T>` class.

However, when I introduce a `where` query expression, that doesn't resolve the type of the receiver.

The `Select` expression works just fine.

I used to know this at the back of my hand until 18 months ago, which was the time I implemented a trivial LINQ provider. I have since forgotten much of it.

Could you please list the bare minimum requirements for all this to work?

```
using System;

namespace CompilerDoesNotCareAboutTypeLINQQuerySyntax
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // What are the minimum requirements on Foo<T>()?
            // How does it resolve this expression new Foo<string>
            // such that it knows that Foo<string> has many Bar<string>
            // or whatever foo in the query below might resolve to?
            var query = from foo in new Foo<string>()
                        /* where foo. // when I do foo., only the system.object inherited properties of Foo show up */
                        select foo;
        }
    }

    public class Foo<T>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Foo<T> Where<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            return new Foo<T>();
        }

        /*IEnumerator<Foo<T>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new List<Foo<T>>().GetEnumerator();
        }*/
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Foo<R> Select<T, R>(this Foo<T> foo, Func<T, R> transformer)
        {
            return new Foo<R>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here's an update of the `Where` method declaration after implementing the fix that Servy pointed out.

```
class Foo<T>
{
  public Foo<T> Where(Func<T, bool> predicate)
  {
    return new Foo<T>();
  }
}
```

That fixes the bug due to which `foo` in the above query expression query resolved to `system.object`. However, it now resolves to `string`, which, by inference, is the generic type parameter type of the `Where` method.

It earlier resolved to `object` because I had overloaded the generic type parameter `T` as Servy pointed out, and now it resolves to `T`, which is the generic type parameter of the declaring type `Foo<T>`.

The question still remains:
What is the bare minimum requirement on the sequence expression `new Foo<string>()`? It looks like there is none? Then what is the correlation between the value of the expression that will sit in the place of the sequence and the type of the range variable `foo`? If I had to make it such that `new Foo<T>` returned *many foos* and therefore the `foo` in the query `from foo in new Foo<T>()...` resolved to a single `Foo<T>`, what would need to be done?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're overloading `T` in your implementation of `Where`.

You define `T` as the generic argument to the type itself, and you *also* define `T` as the generic argument to the `Where` method.  Since the method's argument is "closer" it takes precedence.  This means that the `T` in `Func<T, bool>` is the method arguement's `T`, *but not the class's `T`.  The *class's* `T` is `string`, but the method's `T` cannot be inferred to be anything, which is why you're not seeing `string` members of the parameter.

In this case, it doesn't seem like you need the method to be generic at all, since the type itself is already supplying you with the generic argument.  You'd only need that method to be generic if it was an extension method not on the type itself.  Just make the method not generic and your code will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you. My bad. So it turns out there is absolutely no requirement on anything at all to conform to anything?

Comment: When I do a `where foo.` after correcting the problem you highlighted, why does `foo` evaluate to `string`?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 The generic argument of the type is a `string`, and that same generic argument is the parameter to the method, so it has to be a string.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 It needs to be a method named `Where` accepting a single argument that is a delegate single argument and returning a value.

Comment: Sorry I had understood your answer and implemented the fix in my code but had not updated the question. I have now updated the question. I am still at a loss of understanding about the correlation between the sequence expression and the range variable in the above query. I have updated my question to try to be more precise about my confusion.